# Moving Django app to production on aws

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am new to aws and Django. i have created an Django application using aws instance ( Ubuntu ) . The app works fine when tested given a run for on using virtualenv. I have already tried running on virtualenv

Now, i am not clear how to move the app to production. The tutorials i came across are not pretty clear.

Should i keep running the server on my virtualenv using screen or is there any other way to keep the app running?

The application suggests using redis and uses postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like Apache or NGINX to deploy your production app to the cloud. See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/) to get an overview the topic.